# Ionic build error - Unexpected token, Missing appropriate loader

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I am getting the below error when trying to build and only if I try to access a specific page(event page). All other pages work fine. Sorry for the long post, but I don't know how to fix this. I removed the ios and android platorms `ionic cordova platform rm ios`, cleaned npm cache, but nothing.

What's weird is that I cleaned the event page, removed the ios app `ionic cordova platform rm ios` and added it back `... add ios`. With nothing in it, the error still showed `<ion-header no-border [class]="headerBackgroundClass">` even though I removed `[class]="headerBackgroundClass"`. That's when I cleaned npm cache. But it still didn't work

I don't know what else to try.

Only thing I can think of is updating ionic webview to `"cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.0.0",` from `"cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.1.19",`

```
[12:48:28]  ionic-app-script task: "build" 
[12:48:28]  Error: ./src/pages/event/event Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0) You may need an appropriate 
            loader to handle this file type. | <ion-header no-border [class]="headerBackgroundClass"> | <ion-navbar> | 
            <ion-title *ngIf="showTitle == true"> @ ./src/pages/event/event.module.ts 9:0-36 @ ./src lazy @ 
            ./node_modules/ionic-angular/util/ng-module-loader.js @ ./node_modules/ionic-angular/module.js @ 
            ./node_modules/ionic-angular/index.js @ ./src/app/app.module.ts @ ./src/app/main.ts 
Error: ./src/pages/event/event
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| <ion-header no-border [class]="headerBackgroundClass">
|   <ion-navbar>
|     <ion-title *ngIf="showTitle == true">
 @ ./src/pages/event/event.module.ts 9:0-36
 @ ./src lazy
 @ ./node_modules/ionic-angular/util/ng-module-loader.js
 @ ./node_modules/ionic-angular/module.js
 @ ./node_modules/ionic-angular/index.js
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/main.ts
```

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.10",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^4.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/crop": "^4.12.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^4.12.0",
    "@ionic-native/google-plus": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/image-resizer": "^4.12.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/native-page-transitions": "^4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/onesignal": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "angularfire2": "5.0.0-rc.6",
    "com.telerik.plugins.nativepagetransitions": "^0.6.5",
    "cordova-android": "7.1.4",
    "cordova-ios": "4.5.5",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-crop": "^0.4.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-googleplus": "7.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^3.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "firebase": "4.12.1",
    "info.protonet.imageresizer": "^0.1.1",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.22.1",
    "onesignal-cordova-plugin": "^2.3.3",
    "rxjs": "5.5.10",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "config": {
    "ionic_source_map": "source-map"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.3",
    "typescript": "~2.6.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "onesignal-cordova-plugin": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
      "cordova-plugin-crop": {},
      "info.protonet.imageresizer": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "com.telerik.plugins.nativepagetransitions": {},
      "cordova-plugin-googleplus": {
        "REVERSED_CLIENT_ID": "xxx",
        "PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION": "11.8.0"
      }
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "ios"
    ]
```

event.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { EventPage } from './event';
import { SaferPipe } from '../../pipes/safer.pipe';
import { Underscore } from '../../pipes/underscore.pipe';
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';
import { NativePageTransitions } from '@ionic-native/native-page-transitions';
import { DaysPipe } from '../../pipes/days.pipe';

import { HourPipe } from '../../pipes/hour.pipe';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    EventPage,
    SaferPipe,
    Underscore,
    DaysPipe,
    HourPipe
  ],
  providers: [
    InAppBrowser,
    NativePageTransitions
  ],
  imports: [

    IonicPageModule.forChild(EventPage),
  ],
})
export class EventPageModule { }
```

Edit ***

Got it working using a workaround. Created a new component and moved code with minor changes. Everything works now. Not sure what was causing the error.

Comment: Can't you make the upgrade? Might it be that the module `cordova-plugin-ionic-webview` isn't compatible with Ionic@3

Comment: So it would only break one page? The error happens only when I try to view an event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working using a workaround. Created a new component and moved code with minor changes. Everything works now. Not sure what was causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

This message `Error: ./src/pages/event/event Module parse failed:` leads me to think that `EventPage` component references its template file incorrectly.

Your `EventPage` decorator should look something like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'event-page',
    templateUrl: 'event.html'
})
export class EventPage {
```

Check that:

1. Event page template file has `.html` extension, e.g `event.html`.
2. Make sure that in  page decorator the template is referenced using `.html` extension: `templateUrl: 'event.html'` and **not** `templateUrl: 'event'`

Comment: 1. event.html has `.html` extension 2. Template is referenced using `.html` extension. I'm not sure what caused the error, but I just created a new component and just moved the code. Everything works.